# Is ir posible to create a undeletable text file using ipfs?

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to learn if IPFS could be used to publicly store text files that should never be deleted

Comment: once you create file and publish it to other peers. if it will be accessed by others then it want't be able to remove it from ipfs. means if you remove file then it can be accessible from other peer nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your node, or another node has the data pinned*, it will never be deleted. However if no nodes have the data pinned*, ultimately the data will be purged by regular garbage collection.

*Data referenced in MFS is also retained.